# Do I need to call jquery library in my application.html.erb file?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ruby-on-rails-4

Jquery comes packaged with rails 4, as far as I know. I'm trying to use Jquery mobile on my website, to make it mobile friendly. In some documentation I read for using jquery mobile it said to put between the head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js" %>

 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Do I really need to call jquery-1.10.2.min.js, if it's already bundled with my app - ruby 4/ rails 2?

In my application.js I have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to call in application.html.erb

Rails also creates a default app/assets/stylesheets/application.css file which contains these lines:

```
    /* ...
    *= require_self
    *= require_tree .
    */
```

Rails 4 creates both app/assets/javascripts/application.js and app/assets/stylesheets/application.css regardless of whether the --skip-sprockets option is used when creating a new rails application. This is so you can easily add asset pipelining later if you like.

The directives that work in JavaScript files also work in stylesheets (though obviously including stylesheets rather than JavaScript files). The require_tree directive in a CSS manifest works the same way as the JavaScript one, requiring all stylesheets from the current directory.

In this example, require_self is used. This puts the CSS contained within the file (if any) at the precise location of the require_self call. If require_self is called more than once, only the last call is respected.

More Details [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)

Comment: Ok, so I need to drop the entire jquery library into my js folder?

Comment: if you are using jquery-rails gem then no need jquery library in js folder but you have mention in application.js file like //= require jquery if you are not using you have to put  jquery library into js folder More info https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails

Answer (score 0):

No, if you drop the jquery mobile js file into your `assets\javascripts` directory it should pick it up as long if you have this line in your `application.js` file: `//= require_tree .`